# Okta Client Assign Users to App

Tags: python, okta

I'm using Okta for Single Sign On, and I'm trying to figure out how I can script assigning users to specific applications. I am currently syncing with AD so the users are already in their groups, I'm just not sure how to confirm assignments to their apps. Below is the API Documentation. I'm doing this in Python.

http://developer.okta.com/docs/sdk/core/python_api_sdk/api/clients/UsersClient.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not currently supported in the Python SDK, but there is an endpoint where you can [assign groups to applications](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps.html#application-group-operations).

Comment: Maybe you'll know how to answer this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540973/assigning-okta-application-to-authorization-server